# Rough Undercarriage Ride

Tags: nissan, suspension, titan

On my '09 Nissan Titan I get a rough rumbling ride/sound from undercarriage when I get to 40 mph. I have lots of rust issues underneath and lots around the rear drive shaft. Worried that the drive shaft isn't rotating smoothly....what do you think might be giving off this grinding sound & feel?

I also hear a sound when I slowly make a left turn as though something is loose or going to fall off the front suspension.

Comment: any chance of an audio capture? maybe a wheel bearing or u joint going bad any vibration at speed?